# How can I make my sauces shelf stable, other than adding acid into it since my recipe doesn't include much of it?

Tags: food-safety, food-science, food-preservation, canning

I would like to be able to can and sell my own sauces (brown gravy sauce, chile paste sauce). There isn't much acid in the recipe of the chile paste, and Mason Jar for pressure canning is cost prohibiting in my country. Is there any other way to preserve my food products and make it shelf stable? Can I use the jar as on the picture if I were to use boiling-water canning?

[image]

[image]

Comment: About the jars you show, I assume you want to use new jars ? not old ones ?

Comment: I suspect that the lid is more important than the jar.  (the two-part lids for canning jars allows air to escape, then seals itself as it cools)  Factory made products use one-part lids, but I don't know what's required to get them to seal.  The closest that I can think of that you can get without two-part lids at home is parifin sealing, but that's only for short-term storage (of low-sugar items), and I suspect that most health inspectors wouldn't be happy with that for commercial products.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way at all to do that.

If you made up your own recipe, pressure canning is out of the question. It is only safe for recipes which have been developed and tested with pressure canning in mind.

Water bath canning is generally also only advised with recipes which have been developed and tested for canning, in order to ensure that you have both the proper acidity and proper thermal behavior. If you have the skills and tools to measure pH, you might decide to go with that and do water-bath canning of your own recipes with testing each batch before and after canning. This might do it for you personally, but 1) you will have to develop recipes that taste pretty sour (which you don't want to), 2) you will still have to use proper canning jars (as answered to your previous questions, both pressure and water bath canning require Mason or Weck style jars, jars with twist-off lids as in your picture are not safe) and 3) if you are selling, your local food safety authority might not agree that it is safe just because you say you measured it.

The only feasible storage option available to you as a home cook is freezing, which makes it almost impossible to operate as a cottage food producer - you would have to ensure that the jars stay frozen the whole time until they reach the customer and the customer would have to consume them within 3-5 days of defrosting, plus it is likely to mess with the texture of some sauces.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to pasteurize it or can it to sell it safely and not have issues with bacteria or botulism ..

Answer (score -1):

It is absolutely possible to do this however it is not simple. Your microorganism control toolkit consists of:

- water activity
- temperature
- ph
- salinity
- oxygen levels
- enzymatic activity from beneficial microorganisms
- preservatives (not recommended by me)

The more types of control you use the less of any type is required, but there is no magic formula. You need to educate and test.

There is type of sous-vide bag suitable for canning called a retort bag

I would be buying (or "borrowing" from the library of genesis) a number of books ranging from home-canning, to modernist cuisine, to proper food science books targeted at manufacturers.